# skipping Error 404 with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrap some URL with BeautifulSoup. The URL I'm scraping are coming from a google analytics API call, some of then aren't working properly so I need to find a way to skip them.

I tried to add this:

```
except urllib2.HTTPError:
continue
```

But I got the following syntax error :

```
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is my full code:

```
rawdata = []
urllist = []
sharelist = []
mystring = 'http://www.konbini.com'
def print_results(results):
  # Print data nicely for the user.

  if results:
    for row in results.get('rows'):
      rawdata.append(row[0])
  else:
    print 'No results found'

  urllist = [mystring + x for x in rawdata]

  for row in urllist:  
            # query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
    page = urllib2.urlopen(row)
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
    continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

                # Take out the <div> of name and get its value
    name_box = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'nb-shares'})
    if name_box is None:
      continue
    share = name_box.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing

    # save the data in tuple
    sharelist.append((row,share))

  print(sharelist)
```

Comment: What syntax error do you get?

Comment: I update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to catch a *404*, you need to check the code returned or raise the error or else you will catch and ignore more than just the 404:

```
import urllib2
from bs4  import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urljoin


def print_results(results):
    base = 'http://www.konbini.com'
    rawdata = []
    sharelist = []
    # Print data nicely for the user.
    if results:
        for row in results.get('rows'):
            rawdata.append(row[0])
    else:
        print 'No results found'
    # use urljoin to join to the base url
    urllist = [urljoin(base, h) for h in rawdata]
    for url in urllist:
        # query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
        try: # need to open with try
            page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
            if e.getcode() == 404: # check the return code
                continue
            raise # if other than 404, raise the error

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        # Take out the <div> of name and get its value
        name_box = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'nb-shares'})
        if name_box is None:
            continue
        share = name_box.text.strip()  # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing

        # save the data in tuple
        sharelist.append((url, share))

    print(sharelist)
```

Comment: I guess you're right because now I'm script is stuck into an infinite loop !

Comment: @SimonBreton. the urllib2.HTTPError would catch multiple exceptions,  you should only allow what you expect to be caught, any other errors should be raised or you could miss something important,

Comment: If I'm not doing `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`before running my script I got this 'ascii' codec error. However If I'm do using `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` before running my script, nothing happen...no error but not result... my script just seem to be stuck...

Comment: @SimonBreton,  then it is not stuck, it is still running. Add a print in the loop to see what is happening

Comment: Yep thanks. I've tried to reduce the number of url and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Your `except` statement is not preceded by a `try` statement. You should use the following pattern:

```
try:
    page = urllib2.urlopen(row)
except urllib2.HTTPError:
    continue
```

Also note the indentation levels. Code executed under the `try` clause must be indented, as well as the `except` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Two errors:
1. No `try` statement
2. No indentation

Use this:

```
for row in urllist:  
          # query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen(row)
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax error is due to the fact that you're missing a `try` with your `except` statement.

```
try:
    # code that might throw HTTPError
    page = urllib2.urlopen(row)
except urllib2.HTTPError:
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by others,

1. try statement missing
2. Proper indentation missing.

You should use IDE or Editors so that you won't face such problems, Some good IDE and Editors are

- IDE - Eclipse Use [Pydev](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pydev-python-ide-eclipse) plugin
- Editors - [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Anyways, Code after try and indent

```
rawdata = []
urllist = []
sharelist = []
mystring = 'http://www.konbini.com'


def print_results(results):
    # Print data nicely for the user.
    if results:
        for row in results.get('rows'):
            rawdata.append(row[0])
    else:
        print 'No results found'
    urllist = [mystring + x for x in rawdata]
    for row in urllist:
        # query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
        try:
            page = urllib2.urlopen(row)
        except urllib2.HTTPError:
            continue

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    # Take out the <div> of name and get its value
    name_box = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'nb-shares'})
    if name_box is None:
        continue
    share = name_box.text.strip()  # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing

    # save the data in tuple
    sharelist.append((row, share))

    print(sharelist)
```